# How to run npm serve using forever?

Tags: node.js, forever, shipitjs

My end goal is to automate my development using Shipit. I can drop the code on the server properly, but I cannot get the command `NODE_ENV=production forever start -c 'npm run serve'` to execute properly. When I tried running it locally on my server, this is the response I got (a help output). I need to run `npm serve` because it runs the following: `"serve": "gulp build && npm-run-all --parallel gulp-watch jekyll-serve"`. My project is a fork of [Tabler](https://github.com/tabler/tabler).

```
root@server:/var/www/server# cd /var/www/server/current/front-end/ && NODE_ENV=production forever start -c 'npm run serve'
help:    usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
help:    
help:    Monitors the script specified in the current process or as a daemon
help:    
help:    actions:
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another option if that forever doesn't work , for keeping your script file always running in background you can use the

> PM2 npm

refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

OR 
second option is that you can use the

> tmux

you can use this and it allows you run the npm serve same as you run on local system  providing you the link below

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-tmux-on-ubuntu-12-10--2

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get the command `npm run serve` to work. Any suggestions as to how I can achieve that?

Comment: @user82395214 Hey i have made the changes and i have provide the solution and the link you can refer that , i gurante that this will work because i have also use this to run the `npm run serve`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the absolute path for the folder you want to serve, and also use `which` to get the command absolute path as well.

I use npx to run serve instead of having it installed, and it works like this:

```sh
forever start $(which npx) serve -l 80 -s /home/user/folder/build/
```

Comment: I did it... Now forever stop won't stop it!